# Process of mail analysis

Tags: email, spam

We've been receiving some pretty well executed spear phishing attempts, they know staff in specific depts and our MD's  name.  We use Claranet so raise an incident when these come through and they send the offending mail off to Symantec for analysis who 'flag it as spam'.

What analysis process happens to the mail and how are those results used to improve  spam detection. I presume there's a little more to it than check headers and blacklist the sender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Symantec does with the specific mail is probably their secret sauce and also depends on the mail. But common things are

- Adding "signatures" to anti malware programs in case the mail contained malicious attachments.
- Updating the reputation filter for web sites in case the mail contained links to sites where the attacker tried to grab credentials or deliver malware.
- Updating reputation of sender IP address so any mails from this address gets marked as harmful.

These updated rules then get shipped to all their customers so they can profit from your finding the same you can profit from their finding.